# Problems with updating custom css in Hugo - settings issue or cache?

Tags: css, caching, browser, hugo

I'm really confused with Hugo now, I'm only learning. I want to create custom CSS. I added that to my static folder under the name `style.css`. The content is as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif ;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    color: #ffffff ;
}

main {
    max-width: 800px ;
    margin: auto ;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center ;
}

footer {
    text-align: center ;
    clear: both ;
}
```

in my baseof.html layout I've got:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/style.css'>
```

I also updated the CSS in the themes/static folder for debugging purposes:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif ;
    background: #0000ff;
    color: #ccc ;
}

main {
    max-width: 800px ;
    margin: auto ;
}

img {
    max-width: 100% ;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center ;
}

footer {
    text-align: center ;
    clear: both ;
}
```

All other changes I make in the layout and content are updated in the browser correctly. But the background colour remains black. To be specific it is `#110000` which is the original background colour from the themes. I don't know why this colour is still applied and I don't know how to change it.

--EDIT--
Suddenly the colour changed from the correct (custom) css. But now I cannot update it again. Is it a cache issue? I'm using Chromium (on Ubuntu) and I disabled the cache in the developer tools console, but that doesn't help. What should I do?